# SQL - How to append a period

Tags: sqlite

I have an existing SQLite_table like this:

```
startdate  -   enddate
2018-01-01  -  2018-06-30
2018-07-01  -  2018-12-31
2019-01-01  -  2019-06-30
2019-07-01  -  2019-12-31
2020-01-01  -  2020-06-30
2020-07-01  -  2020-12-31
2021-01-01   - 2021-06-30
```

What is the SQL-Statement for the result;
The result should be:

```
2019-11-01  2020-12-31  // 60  Days difference
2020-01-01  2020-06-30  // 180 Days difference
2020-07-01  2020-12-31  // 180 Days difference
2021-01-01  2021-06-30  // 180 Days difference
```

`'2019-11-01'` is entered via the search field in my Android app as input
The point is the output of the small period at the beginning / the
insertion of the first period in the statement
I tried 'Union' and it gives me an error.

How can I do this with a query ?

I am thankful for any help

and what is the SQL statement, when it should
return data from '2019-11-01' until 'now'

```
2019-11-01  2020-12-31  // 60  Days difference
2020-01-01  2020-06-30  // 180 Days difference
2020-07-01  2020-12-31  // 180 Days difference
2021-01-01  2021-02-16  // 46 Days difference ! !
```

Thank's

Answer (score 0):

You need all the rows where `enddate` is less or equal than `'2019-11-01'`:

```
SELECT MAX(startdate, '2019-11-01') startdate, enddate
FROM tablename
WHERE enddate >= '2019-11-01'
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=a6676ecda2b89dc086e40cc27543c788).
Results:

| startdate | enddate |
| --- | --- |
| 2019-11-01 | 2019-12-31 |
| 2020-01-01 | 2020-06-30 |
| 2020-07-01 | 2020-12-31 |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021-06-30 |

Edit, for your 2nd question:

```
SELECT MAX(startdate, '2019-11-01') startdate, 
       MIN(enddate, CURRENT_DATE) enddate
FROM tablename
WHERE enddate >= '2019-11-01' AND startdate <= CURRENT_DATE
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=957b3960120ba1c7a3ec7a1517b789b2).
Results:

| startdate | enddate |
| --- | --- |
| 2019-11-01 | 2019-12-31 |
| 2020-01-01 | 2020-06-30 |
| 2020-07-01 | 2020-12-31 |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021-02-16 |